# Why isn't on_message working with my discordpy code?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My on_message code isn't working can someone tell me what's wrong or tell me what I did wrong?
There are no errors in the console saying I did something wrong also the bot has permissions to send messages.

```py
@client.listen('on_message')
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.lower == "good morning":
    await message.channel.send(f"Good Morning!")
  elif message.content.lower == "goodmorning":
    await message.channel.send(f"Good Morning!")
  elif message.content.lower == "gm":
    await message.channel.send(f"Good Morning!")
  elif message.content.lower == "good night":
    await message.channel.send(f"Good Night!")
  elif message.content.lower == "goodnight":
    await message.channel.send(f"Good Night!")
  elif message.content.lower == "gn":
    await message.channel.send(f"Good Night!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.content` is a `str`, making `message.content.lower` a function which will never be equal to any of your string conditions.

Additionally, your code will be more efficient if you compute `message.content.lower()` once at the start of the function instead of once per conditional and you can also reduce the number of conditionals for readability.

Try this...

```py
My on_message code isn't working can someone tell me what's wrong or tell me what I did wrong? There are no errors in the console saying I did something wrong also the bot has permissions to send messages.

@client.listen('on_message')
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content.lower()
  r = None
  if msg in ["good morning", "goodmorning", "gm"]:
    r = "Good Morning!"
  elif msg in ["good night", "goodnight", "gn"]:
    r ="Good Night!"

  if r is not None:
      await message.channel.send(r)
```

Comment: That works and thanks for telling me that info. I will make sure to that next time.